How to update the column data for multiple records to target value and ignore those NULL column?
Currently I have some table table need to be clean up.



Id
FirstName
Last Name
Email
Created_On




R1
Jack
NULL
testing@gmail.com
2024-08-01


R2
Mandy
Rose
NULL
2024-08-02



What I plan to do is to update my table data for all firstName, lastName, and email column data become the value same as Id, but those column is NULL remain as usual. Is there any simple and faster way I can check the column is NULL or not when I do the update statement?
I only know I can update the column value to same as Id with using query below. but not sure how can I check EVERY column of different row of data if it is null or not.
UPDATE profile_table
SET FirstName = Id, LastName= Id, Email = Id
WHERE Created_On >='2024-08-01'

Anyone can give some guide on these? Thank you so much.

LastName= case when lastname is null then lastname else id end

Mysql or SQL server? They are quite different

@BingHao What is so hard to add a tag of your used rdbms to your question, which do you use?

You could update the 3 columns with the help of 3 CASE expressions:
UPDATE profile_table
SET FirstName = CASE WHEN FirstName IS NOT NULL THEN Id ELSE FirstName END,
    LastName = CASE WHEN LastName IS NOT NULL THEN Id ELSE LastName END,
    Email = CASE WHEN Email IS NOT NULL THEN Id ELSE Email END
WHERE
    Created_On >= '2024-08-01';

An update on a row should only happen if at least one of the 3 columns be non NULL, so we could modify the above to:
UPDATE profile_table
SET FirstName = CASE WHEN FirstName IS NOT NULL THEN Id ELSE FirstName END,
    LastName = CASE WHEN LastName IS NOT NULL THEN Id ELSE LastName END,
    Email = CASE WHEN Email IS NOT NULL THEN Id ELSE Email END
WHERE
    Created_On >= '2024-08-01' AND
    (FirstName IS NOT NULL OR LastName IS NOT NULL OR Email IS NOT NULL);

Going a step further, we could replace the CASE expressions with some function like IFNULL(), but as you tagged with multiple databases, I stuck with ANSI SQL only.

Problem could be solved simply by using Case statements but If you need more control on the new value of a fields you can use this approach.
For modularity split the new value part for a field from the main update part by creating ConvertValue function as follows.
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CValue](@Field NVARCHAR(50),@Id NVARCHAR(10))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(50)
    IF @Field is Null 
     SET @Value=Null 
    ELSE
     SET @Value=@Id   

    RETURN @Value
END

Then check if the target situation achieved with a select query as follows.
SELECT dbo.[CValue](FirstName,Id) FirstName,
       dbo.[CValue](LastName,Id) LastName,
       dbo.[CValue](Email,Id) Email
FROM profile_table
WHERE Created_On >='2024-08-01'


As can be seen from the above picture result, It is ok.
Then update the table with the following query.
UPDATE P
SET FirstName = dbo.[CValue](FirstName,Id), 
    LastName= dbo.[CValue](LastName,Id), 
    Email = dbo.[CValue](Email,Id)
FROM [profile] P
WHERE Created_On >='2024-08-01'


Note that OP seems to be using MySQL or Postgresql.

Also note that case is an expression, not statement. And tables have columns, not fields.

@jarlh you can google Case statement. ttps://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7703/sql-case-in-where-clause/

@FevziKartal And you could read here what is the difference

@jarlh: Note that OP seems to be using MySQL or Postgresql.
My solution is a general aproach. I used Ms Sql syntax but noting to specific for Ms Sql.
Create Function  is a common  routine.
The solution directly  could be used for MS Sql but for others, after little syntax change

@Jonas Metzler with the assumption of MySql question you are correct. Thanks a lot. for the link but It could be MS Sql and this probability :) is greater. than others I think.
So my assumption and namings is for MS Sql. Solution could easily be modified for others.

The RDBMS does not matter for the difference between case statement and case expression.

Using the name of RDBMS is enough to answer which is related case statement or case expression.

mssqltips' 'The SQL CASE statement specifies a conditional expression' is plain wrong, and very confusing.

Not just mssqltips. Mysql could have different definition for Case Statements and Case Expression but Im mostly using Ms Sql - Tsql and a google search shows that Profesionals widely accept the Case Statement not Case Expression like we learned years ago.

A case expression returns a value. A case statement can be used in stored procedures for conditional execution of code.

@jarlh thanks for comment but a Case Statement already contains a case expression.  Case is similar to If and we define as If Statement not If expression but If statement contains If expression. Statements assigns, changes the value of a variable but expressions are just a criteria they cant change vairable's value. techonthenet,
gur99
